# Proper alignment of thumbnails generated via php on bootstrap framework

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, thumbnails

I want to divide my 12 column space in to two categories of 3 and 9 col width.on the first side i have some information and on second 9 columns width i want to display automatically generated content through php using mysql.Here is the first side
First side code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="well">some content</div>
<div class="well1">some content2</div>
</div>
```

Here is the second side automatically generated coded:

```
    <div class="col-md-9">


 <?php extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
include "cw_admin/pageing.php";
$limit = 30;                                
if($page) 
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
else
$start = 0;                     
$filePath="trending.php";
$select="select * from offers where trending='Yes' order by guid desc  Limit $start, $limit ";
$select1="select * from offers where trending='Yes'";
$result=mysql_query($select,$con);
$total=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($select1,$con));
$otherParams="catid=$catid&shopid=$shopid"; 

        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $det=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from category where id='$row[cat_id]'"));
     $shop=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from shop where guid='$row[shopname]'"));?>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">

<?php if($shop[imagefile]!=''){?><img src="imagefiles/<?php echo $shop[imagefile];?>" class="img-responsive" "><?php } ?>

<div class="caption">
<h4 class="pull-right"><?php echo $row[rate];?></h4>
        <h4><?php echo $row[productname];?></h4>
 <p><?php echo $row[description];?></p>
         <p><?php if($row[offer_end]!='0000-00-00'){?>Offer Ends On: <?php echo $row[offer_end];}?></p>
        <p><?php if($row[coupon]!=''){?>Coupon Code:<?php echo $row[coupon];?><?php } ?></p>
 <?php 
                                 if($_SESSION[userid]!='')
                                { ?>
                                <a  href="<?php echo $row[main_url];echo "&";echo $row[affid];echo "&";echo $row[memid];echo "=";echo $details[userid];echo $row[deepid];?>"  target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" > Earn <?php echo $row[value];?> Points</a>
                                <?php } 
                               else { ?>
                                <a  href="#1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" class="btn btn btn-primary" >Earn <?php echo $row[value];?> Cash</a>
                                <?php };
                                ?> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>


</div>


</div>
</div>
```

I have two questions:
1)i gave 2 side as col-md-9 as outer and col-md-3 as inner but still in my output there are 4 items in the list.!
2)Even if a small increase in the height of thumbnail it results in removal of thumbnail in the next row.Pls i am a new bie help me in this..we got cheated by a designer so had to do everything again

Comment: Your code is a complete mess and it's going to be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: We are just trying to edit the code the deisgner gave.It was worst so i am trying to edit.Kindly help me in this

Comment: its coming like this eventhough i have given 3 column width and is getting distorted.http://rewardsinn.com/trending2.php  .Kindly help us we caant afford another designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues and how to fix them:

1. There is an extra " in this line: `<?php if($shop[imagefile]!=''){?><img src="imagefiles/<?php echo $shop[imagefile];?>" class="img-responsive" "><?php } ?>` after the `class="img-responsive"`.  If you don't remove it, it's going to make a mess of things for sure.
2. If you have a column and you're nesting other columns inside it, you must add a row or you will have double padding.  The row class adds negative 15px of margin left and right to negate the column padding of the column that the nested columns are inside.  So, create another div with a class of row and wrap it around the col-md-3 div inside of your col-md-9 div.  (See the diagram in my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899715/bootstrap-balancing-bullet-columns/23912463#23912463)** if you need more of an explanation of this concept).
3. col-md-3 is going to give you 4 items in a row.  That's how it works.  The 3 refers to 3 columns of 12 (i.e., 12/3 = 4). If you only want to have 3 items in a row, make it: `col-md-4`.
4. Whether it's your image height or the difference in the number of lines of text, the columns use float: left.  That means that if you have (for example) five columns where the second one is longer than the others, if they are each set to col-md-3, then your 5th column can't float all the way left on the next row, because the second column will be in the way.  There are two simple ways to handle this:

a. Set the floating elements to have a fixed height.  For example, in your case, you could give the thumbnail (or even the col-md-3) a fixed height.

b. Close the row after every grouping of columns that you want to appear in a single line so the elements never wrap.  Closing the row and creating a new one clears the floats.  So, for example, you could structure your code like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
</div> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">...</div> 
</div>
```

To accomplish the second option, you'd have to use a little php to check the length of your result set, then you can use two loops to create the markup for the row and the columns inside each row.

Comment: Thanks for your help..but what id dont understand is the remaining width is of only 9 columns so when i give col-md-3 it should be 9/3=3 thumbnails right.Regarding the distortion i have used masonry jquery plugin so that it automatically adjusts its size.

Comment: Ahh, see, that's not how it works.  Every time you nest a row, each nested row has 12 grid columns as well.  The grid columns aren't a fixed width in a fixed space.  They are percentages.  So if you look at the rule for any col-*-3 it's width is 25%.  Make more sense now?