# How can I avoid breaking Bootstrap columns into rows when I use less than 12 cols?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align a site-name + 2 images as my site header. Using Bootstrap grid layout, I can easily achieve this with a nice looking in medium/large size devices.

```
| site-name                                                        | | image1 | | image2 |
```

However, with small size devices, my 3 columns breaks into 3 rows and the layout is not what I want:

```
| site-name                                                        |
| image1    |
| image2    |
```

As I'm using just 3 small columns, I would like to fit them in the same row since they are using just a few pixels. The result for small screens would be something like:

```
| site-name | | image1 | | image2 |
```

I have created a [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/CR8jgz7vCt). The code below is the best that I could do so far. I've already tried using things like `.pull-right` to avoid adding the empty 8-cols, but the result was the same.

Current code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h2>text1</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <!-- empty -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you consider "small" devices is what Bootstrap would consider "extra small".

This should give you the desired effect:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
    <h2>text1</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-8">
    <!-- empty -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>
</div>
```

You might need to step all the classes up to the next size to get what you want (e.g. "col-sm-4 col-md-1")

Comment: Ty! It seems that the `.hidden-xs` class is the trick to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've used col-sm, and not col-xs (which is more for small screens like mobile).

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <h2>text1</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <!-- empty -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <h2>text1</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read a good explanation here:

[Meaning of numbers in col-md-4 , col-xs-1 , col-lg-2 in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Ty, it works, but Brian's answer has a better layout looking (your suggestion gets the images to be merged).