# How to set form fields size with bootstrap?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a form with bootstrap. Here is my source code:

```
<div class="container">
<form action="" method="post" id="payment-form" novalidate autocomplete="on">
<span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cc-number" class="control-label">Card number formatting <small class="text-muted">[<span class="cc-brand"></span>]</small></label>
    <input id="cc-number" type="tel" class="input-lg form-control cc-number" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" required class="col-md-2">
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cc-exp" class="control-label">Card expiry formatting</label>
    <input id="cc-exp" type="tel" class="input-lg form-control cc-exp" autocomplete="cc-exp" placeholder="•• / ••" required class="col-md-2">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cc-cvc" class="control-label">Card CVC formatting</label>
    <input id="cc-cvc" type="tel" class="input-lg form-control cc-cvc" autocomplete="off" placeholder="•••" required class="col-md-2">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>

  <h2 class="validation"></h2>
</form>
</div>
```

I want to do size="30" for fields. But the fields are still too large and this size doesn't affect fields. What changes should I do?

Comment: Can you please include your source code in your actual question?

Comment: try laying out the form using their grid system. For example, you can wrap the field in a div, and set the class to `col-md-3`. Simply substitute the 3 for whatever width you need.

Comment: Where exactly to use that class? Inside input tag? Or inside div tag which is surrounding the input tag?

Comment: Please advice how to make red the error message for span form-errors in source above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this class
col-md-3 or col-md-2.  Please use width="30px", hope this will help you.
EDITED:
if div is your main tag then put the code like

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="cc-number" class="control-label">Card number formatting <small class="text-muted">[<span class="cc-brand"></span>]</small></label>
        <input id="cc-number" type="tel" class="input-lg form-control cc-number" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" class="col-md-3">
      </div>

or you can use width like


<div class="form-group">
        <label for="cc-number" class="control-label">Card number formatting <small class="text-muted">[<span class="cc-brand"></span>]</small></label>
        <input id="cc-number" type="tel" class="input-lg form-control cc-number" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" style="width:30px !important">
      </div>
```

[Meaning of numbers in col-md-4 , col-xs-1 , col-lg-2 in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap)

please let me know if you have any confusion.\
Thank you

Comment: Where exactly to use that class? Inside input tag? Or inside div tag which is surrounding the input tag?

Comment: What is x is col-md-x? This is px? For example col-md-2 actually means 20px and col-md-4 means 40px?

Comment: Please see my edit.I thin this will help in understanding you the difference of col-md-x etc

Comment: Thanks got it. So col-md-3 means 1/4 of screen width?

Comment: Sorry, none of them are working please copy/paste my code and test in live and advice what is wring there?

Comment: any advice yet please?

Comment: Please advice how to make red the error message for span form-errors in source above?