# Does the order of the these classes; col-sm , col-lg ,col-md & col-xs differ

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, media-queries

I have a question regarding bootstrap 3.0 classes order, now if I write the following where I am starting from sm till lg:-

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 address">
```

will it have any different if I change the class order as follow from lg to sm:-

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4  address">
```

or the order does not matter ?

Comment: Why would you need more than one? Those classes are meant to be used separately are they not? Also, I would assume the first one that shows up in bootstrap.css is the one that would be used.

Comment: Just skimmed this and looks like it's the last one in bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css that will be the one used. 

  If two rules are equal in all of the above, the one declared last wins. CSS embedded in the html always come after external stylesheets regardless of the order in the html

http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: @t03smcg0t3s thanks for the reply.. Now you said that I should define only one class,,, but what if I want to have different col setting based on the screen size,, then it should support multiple class definitions,, is this correct???

Comment: @JohnJohn You can have as many class as you want in single tag. While generating render-tree each css definition comes is applied, so all definition. Hence the last defined css property is being displayed. Check this fiddle for example. https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/heertkud/

Comment: I am not good at explaining so above thing is not well explained. I advice you to read through https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/?hl=en to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 address">`

and

`<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4  address">`

both will be work same.
Check this example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/7hygzjej/)

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but can you advice what is the rule that govern which class will have the effect??? I mean is it about the order of these classes inside the bootstrap.css ??or it is about the order of these classes inside the div???

Comment: at a time only one of a class will be in-effect. It depends on what viewport you are in. If you viewing from Mobile device then `col-*-xs` will be in effect. Checkout this well-written answer for more information : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24177022/923426

Comment: ok thanks for the link ,, but if I say <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> or <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4"> will be exactly the same  ?

Comment: Not at all, order is not important but *-xs-* and *-sm-* are all different class. so interchanging them will change the layout. For sure.

Comment: sorry sorry I mean <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> and <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">  will be the same ,, I mistyped the numbers ... sorry ??

Comment: Yes yes, `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">` and `<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">` are one and the same. Just like looking with one eye, perception changes if you change eye, but the actual thing is at it was.