# Do I need to specify all of the col-xx-xx classes to make a page responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Fairly new to Bootstrap, attempting to convert an existing page into bootstrap tags.

My question relates to grids. On this page http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works/ it says that you only need to use the class for the smallest device width you want to support.

So, if I want to support mobile devices, tablets, medium sized screen and large screens, I only need to type `col-sm-xx`?

If I set a div to

```
<div class="col-sm-6">...</div>
```

I understand that this will take up half the screen size, but will it do the same when `col-md-xx` and `col-lg-xx` breakpoint is hit?

And if so why bother having those md and lg classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of numbers in col-md-4 , col-xs-1 , col-lg-2 in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

The element with `col-6` class will take a half of screen, it doesn't matter, on mobile or on desktop: on every screen. And Bootstrap provides custom breakpoints, so you can write the class like `col-sm-6`, and this rule will be applied only for small devices. Look at the custom Bootstrap's breakpoints and resolutions:

[image]

This option was created to allow developers to change their grid in every breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. But, additionally, you'd use `md` or `lg` breakpoints depending on how you want to show the grid. Example, let say you have **3 columns** that is big enough to be seen on both the tablet (maybe iPad) and desktop Like three photos. But then it wouldn't make sense to show three columns on mobile phone, which should adjust 1 photo on a column. So you'd tell Bootstrap to to show a grid `col-md-4` on each photo but `col-sm-12`.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">photo here</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">photo here</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">photo here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question based on your example; before doing so, it has to be noted that by default a `div` element has a width of 100% or in case of the bootstrap classes, is equal to all `col-XX-12` classes, each one at its responsive tier.

When using the `col-sm-6` on its own and based on the the way the bootstrap grid system works, here is what happens:

a) Since there is no `col-xs-XX` class, the width of the column will default to a normal `div`'s, aka 100%
b) Starting from the `sm` resolution tier - 768px and above - the column would be 6/12 or 50% of the parent width.
c) If there are no other classes for higher resolution tiers, then the 50% width will pass on to all resolutions upwards.

To answer your question, why you should need the rest of the classes used for higher resolution tiers, eg 'col-md-6' or 'col-lg-6'.. you don't, UNLESS of course you want to change the column width to a different width at those resolution tiers.

Moreover, you can also skip classes of intermediate resolution tiers, if the column width remains the same for those resolutions, eg. if you require a column to have a 50% width from 768px and up to 1199px and then have the column consume 66% you would use classes `col-sm-6 col-lg-9` skipping the intermediate `col-md-6` since the value is carried on from the small resolution tier.

As a sidenote, the breakpoints I am referring to are from Bootstrap 3 - are changed for Bootstrap 4 - however, usage remains the same.