# DSpace 6.2 Mirage 2 Footer Modification

Tags: css, sass, dspace

I am having trouble with modification of the footer on the DSpace 6 Mirage 2 theme. I have managed to find where to customize the text content i.e the page_structure file but I can't seem to find the file in which to customize the styling or I could be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, the Mirage2 footer is constructed here.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/core/page-structure.xsl#L700-L750

Note that the bootstrap classes (col-xs, etc) are in place.  The following thread might help: [Meaning of numbers in col-md-4 , col-xs-1 , col-lg-2 in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap)

If you want to change colors, fonts, etc, you should be able to style the descendants of the footer tag.  Here are the existing footer styles in Mirage2.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_general.scss#L133-L170

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the *page-structure.xsl* file found in

```
/home/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/core
```

worked great.