# make space between bootstrap column align one below other in small device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

- In this example there are two column `col-sm-3`, `col-sm-8` in one row.
- After minimize the window (refer screenshot) the two column are sticking 
     to each other.
  -Also second column ie col-sm-8 is not taking full width at sm breakpoint.

  note: want to main space between columns at sm breakpoint, also want full 
  size of col-sm-8.

  [link to bootstrap code](https://codepen.io/yash0123/pen/XGMXmv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just add class then `col-sm-8` will be full width and also space between columns at sm breakpoint

Add this below calss on `col-sm-8` div `only`:

`<div class="col-sm-8 mt-3 mt-md-0 p-0 px-md-3">`

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "80px";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
    >
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
   <style>
       .nav-pills .nav-link.active{
           color: rgb(12, 11, 11) !important;
           background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
       }
       html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #1d1c1c;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
  font-size: 80%;
}

   </style>
</head>
<body>
        <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">


                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                              </a>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                </nav>
        </header>


        <main role="main" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-white bg-secondary pt-2 pb-2" >

                <div class="nav  flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                        <a class="nav-link  text-light active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Profile</a>
                        <a class="nav-link text-light  " id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                        <a class="nav-link text-light " id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-8 mt-3 mt-md-0 p-0 px-md-3">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active " id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header card-title"><b>Profile</b></div>
                            <div class="card-body">Panel Content</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header card-title"><b>Messages</b></div>
                            <div class="card-body">Panel Content</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header card-title"><b>Settings</b></div>
                            <div class="card-body">Panel Content</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                  <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
                </div>
              </footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @Mohit Gupta

Answer (score 2):

You could add some `margin` on a `breakpoint` like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm-8 {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

The `sm` keyword means small in bootstrap, which breaks at `576px`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap) explains it pretty well

**Full width**

In order to make the last div in full width, you can see why it isn't full width at the start by inspecting it.

[image: Padding]

As you can see it has padding in each side - `padding: 15px`. We can remove it in a breakpoint, to keep the space in higher resolutions.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm-8 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is your code, with the new code

[**Codepen example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLpNqX)

Comment: Thanks @Marc Hjorth

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use all Bootstrap margin properties. In that case, I think mb-3 (margin-bottom-3) or mt-3 (margin-top-3) should be what you are looking for.

Note that with pure CSS you can also add a margin if the width is superior to X px.

For example :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .do_margin_bottom {
        margin-bottom:20px; /* Equivalent of mX-3 */
    }
}
```

Then apply .do_margin_bottom to your col-sm-3.

For the second point : Your col-sm-8 is correctly indented, as your col-sm-3. This is your div.card that is adding margin-left:15px & margin-right:15px. You should set thoses values on your card element to get what you want.

I personnally recommand you not doing this. A card without margins is weird.