# trying to set up css panels, and failing miserably with scaling :(

Tags: html, css, panel, scaling

the page i am making is at http://kamikazeproductions.net/tooth/kpbr0009.html in browser it looks ok, still needs some finessing... but when i reduce/resize the browser window, or if i navigate via mobile browser, the 2 vertical panels overlap :( 
the idea was to set it up somewhat like https://www.limitedrungames.com/collections/neo-frontpage/products/streets-of-red-ps4, but that page has 3000 lines of code, and css is mostly greek to me. so i can't figure out how its done. i miss the days of html 3.0 lol

so my problems.... the idea is to have a horizontally centered banner panel at the top, 2 vertical panels, and a horizontally centered panel at the bottom. 
1) as stated earlier, the vertical panels overlap when resized, instead of dynamically scaling. can't figure out how to set a hard break between the 2.
2) lower panel is WAAAYYY lower than i want it. i just want to lower panel 2 or 3 lines below the 2 vertical panels. any help?
3) i wouldn't mind having about 20px of space or so between the left image and the left side of the window... but it's not a deal breaker. i tried the ol' `&nbsp;` but it didnt seem to do anything to add spacing. i'm just trying to do a very quick and dirty order page for tomorrow. thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tooth And Nail VHS Collection Blu-Ray</title>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.kamikazeproductions.net/tooth/bg.jpg");
  }

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftpane {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.rightpane {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="toppane">
<center><img src="http://www.kamikazeproductions.net/tooth/banner.png" height="229" width="630"></center><br><br>
    </div>

<div class="leftpane">
<br><br><br><IMG SRC="http://www.kamikazeproductions.net/tooth/package.png" height="504" width="420" ALIGN="left" />
    </div>

<div class="rightpane">
<p><b><font size="5">$23.00, postage included!</b></font>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NR2DBYM5SJESS">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form><br>
<font size="4">blah blah blah<br>
<br clear="all">
    </div>

<div class="bottompane">
<p><center><font size="5">blah blah blah</font><br><br><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LAZKY45-PYM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><br><br><br><br><br> (c) 2020 Kamikaze Productions</center>
</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your image tag contains explicit ratio declarations, it will not be fluid with the containers.

You could either 
1. 
setup a grid system (i use flex box in my example but you could also use true grid) and use some media queries to have the grids stack as a column as the view port shrinks

```
<style>
section[role="container"]{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}


section[role="container"] *{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    section[role="container"]{
    flex-direction: column;
    }
}
</style>
    <section role="container">
        <div class="left-pane">content</div>
        <div class="right-pane">content</div>
    </section>
```

2. set your image size with percentages so the image fills it's container and remains fluid. you could add a max-width min-width if you want to prevent going below a certain resolution.

Comment: option 1 got it to work! now we are in business. i'm really just brute forcing this thing so i went into PS and added more pad on each side of the image to give it more spacing. not ideal for most, but it works in a pinch. thanks for the help!

Comment: awesome! I checked your site again and see that it is scaling now, however I wouldsuggest you setup multiple @media blocks for various break points (i.e. when sizing for TV, large monitor, small monitor, tablet, phone).

And then I would suggest setting the max width for your column stack to the size of the image with a explicit ratio. (max-with : whatever the width of your image is).. this way there is never any overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap and css like **col-lg**, **col-md**, **col-xs** and so on... to provide your webpage for normal Manitor, Tablet size, mobile size, etc

You should read below link:

[Meaning of numbers in "col-md-4"," col-xs-1", "col-lg-2" in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap)