# how to rearrange bootstrap columns in order on mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

how to rearrange bootstrap columns? i have a 2 column layout on desktop view

this is what i have in desktop view

[image]

im trying to achieve this layout on mobile view, is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer

Template

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 top-features">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 item-brand">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12"><4/div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">5</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">6</div>
```

Styles

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {

  .top-features {
    order: 2;
  }

  .item-brand {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable this you will want to have each div include the following classes:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Look into the bootstrap grid system for more info.

Comment: Here is a similar question that explains the grid system well. Please select my answer as correct if it answered your question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175998/meaning-of-numbers-in-col-md-4-col-xs-1-col-lg-2-in-bootstrap]