# why do we need class .row in bootstrap framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I looked into the bootstrap.css, and didn't quite understand. 
The only codes about .row looks like this.
Why and when do we need .row in bootstrap?

```
.row {
 margin-right: -15px;
 margin-left: -15px;
}
.row:before,
.row:after{display: table;
 content: " ";
}
.row:after{
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The article in the selected answer is great. Here's a concise version of the explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899715/bootstrap-balancing-bullet-columns/23912463#23912463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row is a wrapper to contain the columns. Column gutters are offset for the first and last column with the negative row margin. If you didn't have them, you'd see a horizontal scrollbar on your content.
[Solid Article on the B3 Grid System](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works).

For proper alignment they should be inside a container.