# Bootstrap pull-right align issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty noobish at CSS, but I've been playing around with Bootstrap 3 for a couple weeks. That said, I'm sorry if the question is too easy/repeated. I've searched around (both Google and Stackoverflow), but didn't find the answer to my issue (probably because I don't know how to query for it =/).

Thing is, I'm trying to have a link (  element ) that I want vertically aligned with a button (). Also, I want the button to be on the right of the container. Here's a fiddle that shows the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/69bmm/

```
<div class="row">
    <a href=";">Text I want vertical-middle</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Button</button>
</div>
```

In the fiddle, I add the pull-right class to the button, and the elements are in the position I want them to be, but I wanted the link-text to be aligned with the button-text, but it doesn't matter what padding or margin I add to the  element, I can't align them.

What I've tried to solve:

- Encapsulate both  and  elements in a div each, and set "float:right" to the latter, removing the pull-right class. (http://jsfiddle.net/66zbh/)
- Encapsulate  in a div with col-md-8 and the , without the pull-right class, in a col-md-4, they get vertically aligned as I want them, but the button isn't pulled to the right

Thank you very much!

Comment: As @sw4 stated, line-height is a good solution, but I would put it on the anchor tag.  Also, you stated that you are new to both css and Bootstrap, so I just wanted to point out that you are using the row incorrectly.  Rows must have columns inside of them.  For a quick understanding about the grid, you can take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899715/bootstrap-balancing-bullet-columns/23912463#23912463

Comment: Thank you for your concern! Your answer is really complete and well-explained about the grid system, but in the actual html, I wasn't using rows for this, only in the fiddle ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `line-height` for the `.row` to be the same height as your button:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69bmm/1/)

```
.row{ /* <-- you will want to add better specificity here, e.g. refer to the specific element by id */
    line-height:34px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had already tried setting the <a> height to 34px and vertical-align to middle, but to no use! Thank you =)